# PHP MySQL get SUM for only certain entries using SELECT

Tags: php, sql

On the table below how would I write a select clause for the SUM of prices for a particular year, say 2013? something like SUM(price WHEN year = 2012). And how would I refer to that result in PHP mysql_fetch_array().

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Price | Date | Month | Year |

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

9.00  |343345|   2   | 2013 |

3.00  |343445|   2   | 2013 |

4.00  |343245|   1   | 2013 |

1.00  |342245|   1   | 2013 |

5.00  |333355|   12  | 2012 |
```

Comment: did you really separate a date in to multiple columns? 5 minutes i n the manual page for SELECT would probably answer the basics of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an alias:

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS my_sum 
WHERE year = 2102
```

Then in php:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['my_sum'];
```

Comment: `SUM(price WHEN year = 2012)` - unless I'm mistaken, that's not a valid expression

Answer (score 1):

`select sum(price) from table where year = 2012;`

You would refer to it by using:

```
$data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $data[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

The query for this will be the below one:

```
select sum(price) as total_price from your_table_name where Year='2012';
```

And in PHP you can use it as:

```
$getTotal = mysql_query("select sum(price) as total_price from your_table_name where   Year='2012'");
while($resTotal = mysql_fetch_array($getTotal))
{
 $total = $resTotal['total_price'];
}
```

now you have the total in a variable $total

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: ^^^^as true as it is, its getting a little tedious for regular S.O users to see it 10+ times a day